# Linq Get the Max() Value of a Group and assign it to that group

Tags: c#, linq, collections, grouping, variable-assignment

This is what i have and works.

```
foreach (var group in groupCollection)
        {
            int maxValue = group.Max(x => {
                int value = 0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(x[index1].ToString(), out value))
                    return value;
                return value;
            }) ;
            foreach (var row in group)
            {
                row[index2] = maxValue;
            }
        }
```

But i was wondering if theres a way to simplify this:
The following code just assigns what each list already has
not the Max value.

```
groupCollection.ForEach(x => x.Max(y=> {
            int value = 0; 
            if(Int32.TryParse(y[index1].ToString(), out value))
                y[index2] = value;
            return value;
            }));
```

Keep in mind that groupCollection is a `List<List<List<object>>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
groupCollection.ForEach(x => {
    int maxValue = x.Max(y =>
        Int32.TryParse(y[index1].ToString(), out var value) ? value : 0);
    x.ForEach(y => y[index2] = maxValue);
    });
```

Comment: Yeah this worked,thanks a lot and i appreciate the way you simplified the TryParse statement, this makes me understand just how powerful linq is,and explains how you're able to use the "{ }" to do multiple things.